# Apache maps all URLs to sub-directory

Tags: linux, apache-http-server

I am hosting a React Application with Apache and performed URL remapping to map a specific URL to the directory on disk where the application lies, in this case /app of the host machine.

However, when running the App and attempting to access a sub-URL of the Application, for example localhost/app/home, it attempts to find the /home directory on disk instead of the /home URL of the application.

How do I pass this to my destination application?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Apache2 destination using the config file to default destination in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` in the line

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/default
```